Windows 10 taskbar icons on second monitor gone after switching monitor off and on again
Situation:
Windows 10 Pro 22H2, 2 monitors (MSI Optix MAG274QRFDE-QD) on NVidia graphics card (MSI GeForce RTX 2070)
Taskbar option "Show taskbar buttons on" set to "All taskbars".
Problem:
Switching monitors off and on again => taskbar icons only shown on main monitor.
Current workaround:
Open options, switch to different option and switch back.
Question:
Is there either:

a fix for the bug itself, so that the taskbar option stays effective?
some kind of script which can change these options (since it is faster to execute a script, than to go to these options)?

